Pre tag with style="white-space: pre-line" removes leading spaces as desired, but how can I prevent it from losing internal spacing?
I'm having an issue with the HTML pre tag. If I do a very simple test it preserves spacing the way that I want it to. For instance, notice that there are two spaces in a row in certain parts of the following example:
<pre>
0 1 2 3 4 ... 
| | | | | 
0 2 4 6 8 ... 

0  1  2  3  4  5  6 ...
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
0  1 -1  2 -2  3 -3 ...
</pre>

However, if I use style="white-space: pre-line" because I want to preserve indentation in my source code, then I lose the desired spacing in the pre tag. For instance, this does not work as I want.
<pre style="white-space: pre-line">
    0 1 2 3 4 ... 
    | | | | | 
    0 2 4 6 8 ... 
    
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6 ...
    |  |  |  |  |  |  |
    0  1 -1  2 -2  3 -3 ...
</pre>

This code with the pre-line style appears like this in the browser:
0 1 2 3 4 ... 
| | | | | 
0 2 4 6 8 ... 

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
| | | | | | |
0 1 -1 2 -2 3 -3 ...

Is there a way to preserve the leading indentation and not lose the internal spacing?
Note: I know there is a way to do this using JavaScript to alter the DOM but I want a straight CSS/HTML solution. I also don't want to use HTML entities to put spacing in.
I tried all of the following but none of them meet my desired requirements:
<pre style="white-space: pre-line">
    0 1 2 3 4 ... 
    | | | | | 
    0 2 4 6 8 ... 
    
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6 ...
    |  |  |  |  |  |  |
    0  1 -1  2 -2  3 -3 ...
</pre>

<pre style="white-space: pre;">
    0 1 2 3 4 ... 
    | | | | | 
    0 2 4 6 8 ... 
    
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6 ...
    |  |  |  |  |  |  |
    0  1 -1  2 -2  3 -3 ...
</pre>

<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <pre style="white-space: pre; margin: 0;">
        0 1 2 3 4 ... 
        | | | | | 
        0 2 4 6 8 ... 
        
        0  1  2  3  4  5  6 ...
        |  |  |  |  |  |  |
        0  1 -1  2 -2  3 -3 ...
    </pre>
</div>

<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <pre style="white-space: pre; margin: 0;">
&#8288;0 1 2 3 4 ...
&#8288;| | | | |
&#8288;0 2 4 6 8 ...

&#8288;0&#8288;1&#8288;2&#8288;3&#8288;4&#8288;5&#8288;6 ...
&#8288;|&#8288;|&#8288;|&#8288;|&#8288;|&#8288;|&#8288;|
&#8288;0&#8288;1&#8288;-1&#8288;2&#8288;-2&#8288;3&#8288;-3 ...
    </pre>
</div>


Can you wrap elements into e.g. table?

No. What you're looking for iswhite-space-trim: discard-inner but browsers don't support it yet.
